# How can I detect whether a hardware device has been plugged or unplugged from my PC through USB port

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

Current effort:
1, hidapi-1.1.jar
2, GetRawInputDeviceList

hidapi-1.1.jar is aborted in my app for some reason.

GetRawInputDeviceList isn't stable in Win10 referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419314/getrawinputdevicelist-and-getrawinputdeviceinfo-fail-to-work-in-win10

I wonder is there any other method to reach my goal?
OS is windows, programming language is not limited.

Comment: The solution you are looking for is for usb devices alone?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java, C++, C, and winforms?

Comment: @hazzelnuttie. Yep, just for usb devices.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. Sorry for the mistake, winforms is changed to windows. The main language in my app is java, so it's better to have a java solution. If the solution is with c/c++, I can call it through JNI too. And for more people to read this question, I have used these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually **SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId** can be used to monitor it. For details, pls refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551106(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hotplug event notification API present in `libusb`. Documentation is here: http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/hotplug.html

In a nutshell, this API lets your program get a callback whenever a device is connected or disconnected, and lets you filter for just the devices you care about (see `libusb_hotplug_register_callback`).

Note that the hotplug API isn't supported on all OSes; if it isn't, you will have to fallback to enumerating devices using `libusb_get_device_list`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the license LGPL is not allowed in our App. Maybe I should find another method.